# GPG error The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: linux, debian, docker, jenkins

I'm following [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) guide for the installation of Docker inside a Jenkins container

This is the Dockerfile of the Jenkins container:

```
FROM jenkins:1.596
 
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# setup docker repository
RUN apt-get install
RUN apt-get update

RUN echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-transport-https \
    && ca-certificates \
    && curl \
    && gnupg-agent \
    && software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
   
# install docker engine
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

USER jenkins
```

When I build the image I get these errors:

```
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9D6D8F6BC857C906 NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
```

Answer (score 1):

Debian jessie is EOL with ExtendLTS support [ELTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended).

Your should have the following lines in your sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://archive.debian.org/ jessie/updates main 
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Alias `apt-get` to `apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false`

Comment: Yes, you need ELTS. But no, `-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false` does not help. This is not the InRelease timestamp which expired as may happen on `archive.debian.org`. It's the GPG key which expired. (And I don't know a currently working and acceptable solution for that either. And `--allow-unauthenticated` is not an acceptable solution.)